# Use spacy on pretokenized text

Tags: python, tokenize, spacy

I want to use spacy for processing an already pre-tokenized text. Parsing a list of tokens to spacy does not work.

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp(["This", "is", "a", "sentence"])
```

This gives a TypeError (which makes sense):
`TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list)`

I could replace the tokenizer with a custom one, but I feel like that would overcomplicate things and is not the preferred way.

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using nlp.pipe() with pre-segmented and pre-tokenized text with spaCy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128766/using-nlp-pipe-with-pre-segmented-and-pre-tokenized-text-with-spacy)

Answer (score 2):

As of spaCy 3.0+, nlp.tokenizer.tokens_from_list() has been deprecated. Use the `Doc` object instead.

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

sent = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence"]

doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, sent)
for token in nlp(doc):
    print(token.text, token.pos_)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```py
tokens = ["This", "is", "a", "sentence"]
sentence = nlp.tokenizer.tokens_from_list(tokens)
print(sentence)
```

```
This is a sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

`sentence = nlp.tokenizer.tokens_from_list(tokens)` with spacy.matcher / Matcher you'll get error:

> Try using nlp() instead of nlp.make_doc() or list(nlp.pipe()) instead
>   of list(nlp.tokenizer.pipe()).

The way I solved it: I iterate over each item inside of a for loop:

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'LEMMA': 'sentence', 'POS': 'NOUN'}]
matcher.add('Searched Word', None, pattern)
X = ["Sentence one", "Sentence two", "Sentence three", "sentence last !"]
for i in X.index:
    doc = nlp(X[i])
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
       matched_span = doc[start:end]
       print(matched_span.text)
```

A a better way of doing this is using **nlp.pipe**:

```
for doc in nlp.pipe(X):
print([token.text for token in doc])
```

Also good for faster algo running and more efficient text processing.

Hope this helps. Thank you.